# View.getId() not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am new to android programming. I want to update the items in a card view layout of a recyclerview. This is the ListRowViewHolder for the recyclerview

```
public static class ListMenuRowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
        protected NetworkImageView thumbnail;
        protected TextView itemname;
        protected TextView price;
        protected TextView itemtype;
        protected TextView quantity;
        protected ImageView add;
        protected ImageView sub;
        protected ImageView imageView;
        protected CardView item_layout;

        public ListMenuRowViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            this.thumbnail=(NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recom);
            this.imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.categ);
            this.itemname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemvalue);
            this.add=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
            this.sub=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub);
            this.price=(TextView)itemView.findViewById((R.id.price));
            this.quantity=(TextView)itemView.findViewById((R.id.quantity));
            this.item_layout=(CardView)itemView.findViewById((R.id.item_layout));
            itemView.setClickable(true);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("myname", "rohit");
                    ItemscardClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

This is where i am trying to update quantity

```
 mAdapter.setItemsCardClickListener(new ItemsCardClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v, int position) {

                    int q;
                    switch (v.getId())
                    {
                        case R.id.add : q= Integer.parseInt(mAdapter.getmOrder().get(position).getQuantity());
                            q++;
                            Log.e("mishra", String.valueOf(q));
                            mAdapter.getmOrder().get(position).setQuantity(String.valueOf(q));
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;
                        case R.id.sub : q=Integer.parseInt(mAdapter.getmOrder().get(position).getQuantity());
                            if(q>0)
                                q--;
                            mAdapter.getmOrder().get(position).setQuantity(String.valueOf(q));
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;
                        case R.id.quantity:
                            Log.e("mishra", "hihi");
                            break;
                        default:Log.e("mishra", "hi");


                    }
                }
            });
```

Everytime when i am clicking on an item in the view they are clicked but i am not getting the id using v.getId(). The switch is always entering the default case. Please provide some solution.

Comment: Are the ids correct for your layout?  Please show your layout that is the source of all these views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the `OnClickListener` on your `View` that contains all of the other subviews and not on the individual subviews themselves. You should let the `ListMenuRowViewHolder` implement `View.OnClickListener` and set a listener on each individual view like so:

```
sub.setOnClickListener(this);
price.setOnClickListener(this);
//etc
```

You can implement

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Now the correct subview gets passed to your switch in the Activity
    ItemscardClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
}
```

in the `ListMenuRowViewHolder`.

So it will look like this:

```
public static class ListMenuRowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected NetworkImageView thumbnail;
    protected TextView itemname;
    protected TextView price;
    protected TextView itemtype;
    protected TextView quantity;
    protected ImageView add;
    protected ImageView sub;
    protected ImageView imageView;
    protected CardView item_layout;

    public ListMenuRowViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recom);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categ);
        this.itemname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemvalue);
        this.add = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        this.sub = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        this.price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        this.quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

        this.add.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.sub.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Do this for each view
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("myname", "rohit");
        ItemscardClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a click listener of the container (itemView). You need to set click listeners on your individual views:

```
this.add.setOnClickListener(mListener);
this.sub.setOnClickListener(mListener);
this.price.setOnClickListener(mListener);
this.quantity.setOnClickListener(mListener);
```

Then declare a listener:

```
View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.add:
               break;
            case R.id.sub:
               break;
            // add others
        }
    }
}
```